# Weird "zu' mit Infinitiv

Tags: word-order, modal-verb, infinitive

> Ich bin dir dankbar, mit mir **gekämpft haben zu können**.

I came across this sentence that seems weird to me. Should it be more like this:

> Ich bin dir dankbar, mit mir **kämpfen können zu haben**.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The first. But are your really thankful for being able to fight with yourself?

Comment: No no some random dude edited my post without asking me. Like he thinks he knows better.

Comment: The random dude was me. Read [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74368/1487) to learn why I did it.

Comment: @MarioBedon: Two issues: 1) the sentence is much more reasonable if it reads *dir* instead of *mir* . The edit was sensible, but you reversed it. 2) There is neither a necessity nor a mechanism in StackExchange to ask for permission for an edit, you may want to re-read https://german.stackexchange.com/help/editing.

Comment: @guidot Imho *mir* is much more reasonable than *dir*. Why would someone be thankful for a fight with someone else?

Comment: @Olafant: In fact I did not notice the *dir* from the main clause. While it achieves, that *mir* is not exactly wrong, it does not improve the sentence in regard to style and further clouds its meaning.

Comment: @guidot Replacing *mir* with *dir* or vice versa doesn't cloud nor clear but changes the meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Using indices to indicate dependency, I assume the intended meaning is the following:

> Ich habe<sub>1</sub> mit ihm kämpfen<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub>.
> *I was able to fight with him.*

As a main clause, but not an infinitive clause, the following would be possible as well; I assume that this meaning is not intended.

> #Ich kann<sub>1</sub> mit ihm gekämpft<sub>3</sub> haben<sub>2</sub>.
> *It's possible that I fought with him.*

Going back to the intended meaning, German speakers have not reached a consensus on how to form the corresponding infinitive clause. The expected variant would be the following:

> mit ihm kämpfen<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub> zu haben<sub>1</sub>

However, this variant never occurs. Instead, there are different replacement constructions, all violating multiple grammatical rules.

> mit ihm haben<sub>1</sub> kämpfen<sub>3</sub> zu können<sub>2</sub> (the *Bech* or *132-variant*)
>
> mit ihm gekämpft<sub>3</sub> haben<sub>1</sub> zu können<sub>1</sub> (the *Vogel* or *312-variant*)

These sentences may prove fruitful for linguistic analysis. For practical purposes, a finite clause should be used instead, where the expected, rule-conforming variant is actually the one being used.

> dass ich mit ihm habe<sub>1</sub> kämpfen<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub>

I named the variants are named after two papers discussing them:

- Gunnar Bech, "Grammatische Gesetze im Widerspruch", *Lingua* 12 (1963), p. 291–299.
- Ralf Vogel, "Skandal im Verbkomplex. Betrachtungen zur Morphologie in infiniten Verbkomplexen des Deutschen", *Zeitschrift für Sprachwissenschaft* 28 (2009), p. 307–346, [link](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/ZFSW.2009.028/html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the translation of the correct sentence:

- Ich bin dir dankbar, mit dir gekämpft haben zu können.
- I am grateful to you to have been able for fighting with you.

The proposed second sentence is simply wrong.

(In you original question you wrote »mit *mir* gekämpft«, but that would mean, that you are grateful to someone to have been able for fighting with yourself. That doesn't make much sense, and I think it was just a typo, so I corrected that in your posting.)

- **mit dir gekämpft haben zu können**
  This is an extended infinitive group that contains the prepositional phrase *»mit dir«* (*with you*) and the core infinitive group *»gekämpft haben zu können«*.
- **gekämpft haben zu können**
  This is the core infinitive group it consists of a participle (it's a second participle), an auxiliary verb in its infinite form, the conjunction *»zu«* and a modal verb in its infinite form.
- **gekämpft**
  This is the past participle II (Partizip II) of the verb *»kämpfen«* (*kämpfen = to fight*).
  The past participle II is often used to form compound past tenses, such as the perfect (*»Ich habe gekämpft« = »I fought«*) or the pluperfect (*»Ich hatte gekämpft« = »I had fought«*). In this particular sentence, however, *»gekämpft«* is part of an extended infinitive construction that is used to express a completed action in terms of its ability or possibility.
- **haben**
  This is an auxiliary verb in the infinitive (*haben = to have*), used with the participle II (*»gekämpft«*) to form the compound past tense (*Perfekt*, which is similar but not equal to English perfect tense) (*»Wir haben gekämpft« = »We fought«*). In this construction, it expresses a completed action.
- **zu**
  This is a conjunction that functions here as part of the infinitive group. It is common for infinitive groups with modal verbs (like *»können« = »can«*) to have the word »zu« between the full verb and the modal verb.
- **können**
  This is a modal verb in the infinitive (*können = can*). Modal verbs are used to express the modality (possibility, ability, necessity, etc.) of an action. In this case, *»können«* expresses the possibility that the action (fighting with you) could take place.

---

Construction where 3 different verbs are used to build the predicate are possible, but they are always clumsy. In such constructions you always have a "normal" full verb, a modal verb and an auxiliary verb. Having them in a *»Infinitiv mit zu* construction makes it even more complicated.

Although such constructions are correct, native speakers try to avoid them, because of their clumsiness.

Comment: Good explanation, but I interpreted the question to be about the temporal order that seems odd or wrong in "Ich bin dir dankbar, mit dir gekämpft haben zu können."

Comment: The statement "The proposed second sentence is simply wrong." is simply wrong. *Der Kampf mit sich selbst ist der schwerste!* (und meiner Ansicht nach der einzig dankenswerte)

Comment: @Olafant: The proposed second sentence containes the sequence *»kämpfen können zu haben.«* This sequence is just wrong. And I can't understand how *»Der Kampf mit sich selbst ist der schwerste!«* could be an argument claiming that *»kämpfen können zu haben«* could be correct. Are you really talking about the second sentence, that Mario proposed?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yes. Imho the proposed sentence is right, the first one is wrong.

Comment: @Olafant Once again, so I understand it: you're stating that "Ich bin dir dankbar, mit mir kämpfen können zu haben." is something a German speaker would say? I can't believe it.

Comment: @HalvarF I didn't say that. The question is: which one is right. Answer: the second one is right.

Comment: @Olafant It's correct but no one would ever use it is a strange thing to say in the realm of languages.

Comment: @HalvarF I didn't say that either. You're putting words in my mouth. I have no idea, what "a german speaker" would use.