# Zu + Infinitiv + Modalverb und das Ganze in Vergangenheit

Tags: verb, verbal-complex

Ich bin in meinen Gedanken aufs folgende Problem gestoßen: Ich will sagen, dass es z.B. eine Person gibt, die nicht in der Lage war, eine Aufgabe zu lösen. Die Frage ist, wie es eigentlich richtig wäre, den o.g. Satz auszudrücken?

> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht gelöst zu haben.

(Grammatikalisch korrekt, aber kein MV vorhanden.)

> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht gelöst haben zu können.

(Grammatikalisch?)

> Er scheint die Aufgabe machen können zu haben *bzw.* zu haben machen können.

Ich habe das Gefühl, der Satz ist inkorrekt, doch wenn man ein Modalverb in Vergangenheit setzt, muss ja das MV sowie das nachfolgende Verb in Infinitiv setzen: *ich habe schwimmen können*.

Comment: Das "scheint" scheint in deiner Spezifikation *dass es eine Person gibt, die nicht in der Lage war, eine Aufgabe zu lösen* nicht vorzukommen. Warum bestehen deine Beispiele darauf?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht ganz

Comment: Dein Ausgangspunkt war "Es gibt eine Person, die nicht....". Deine Beispiele sagen aber "Es gibt eine Person, die *anscheinend* nicht....". Das ist ein anderer Satz.

Comment: Ich will damit Folgendes sagen : es kommt jemand und sieht, dass die o.g Person weint. Er versteht schon, woran es liegt ( er hat die Aufgabe nicht gelöst). Dieser jemand holt sein Handy raus, ruft an und sagt :" hey, Lucia, Patrik weint, er scheint die Aufgabe..." und an der Stelle weiß ich nicht, wie ich den Satz weiter ausdrücken soll.

Comment: Zur Grammatik siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74370/.

Comment: Den Kontext solltest Du in die Frage einfügen mittels [edit]. Warum möchtest Du unbedingt einen Infinitiv mit zu verwenden und nicht einfach "Er hat anscheinend die Aufgabe nicht lösen können."?

Comment: Für mich ist die Frage: Was passiert, wenn man unter *scheinen* einbettet, mit i) *er hat die Aufgabe nicht gelöst*, ii) *er kann die Aufgabe nicht lösen*, iii) *er hat die Aufgabe nicht lösen können*. Bei iii) steigt man aus.

Answer (score 1):

Man kann solche Infinitivgruppen sowohl für die Nichtvergangenheit als auch für die Vergangenheit formulieren.

> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht zu lösen.
>
> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht gelöst zu haben.

Kommt ein Modalverb hinzu, gibt muss dieses außen stehen:

> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht lösen zu wollen.
>
> Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht gelöst haben zu wollen.

Nun ist es so, dass nicht alle Modalverben in jedem Zusammenhang einen Sinn ergeben. Das ist bei deinem Beispiel mit *können* der Fall.

Mit *wollen* stellt sich die Frage nicht, denn hier ergibt sich ganz klar der Sinn, dass er zum Zeitpunkt des Scheinens nicht will, dass man annimmt, er hätte die Aufgabe gelöst.

Answer (score 0):

##### Er scheint nicht in der Lage gewesen zu sein, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

Er scheint nicht gekonnt zu haben, die Aufgabe zu lösen.
Allem Anschein nach war er nicht fähig, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

---

Fangen wir ganz simpel an:

> A: Er löst die Aufgabe.
> B: Er hat die Aufgabe gelöst.

A steht im Präsens, B im Perfekt. Nehmen wir an, es wäre jetzt 10:00 Uhr, dann findet im Satz A die Erarbeitung der Lösung um 10:00 Uhr statt. Im Satz B liegt um 10:00 Uhr bereits eine Lösung vor. Das Erarbeiten der Lösung hat also davor stattgefunden, ein möglicher Zeitpunkt ist 8:00 Uhr.

---

Fügen wir den Anschein hinzu:

> C: Er scheint die Aufgabe zu lösen.
> D: Er scheint die Aufgabe gelöst zu haben.

Der Zeitpunkt der Erarbeitung der Lösung ist im Satz C 10:00 Uhr und im Satz D 8:00 Uhr. Aber der Anschein besteht in beiden Sätzen in der Gegenwart, also um 10:00 Uhr.

C: Jetzt besteht der Anschein, dass die Aufgabe jetzt gelöst wird.
D: Jetzt besteht der Anschein, dass die Aufgabe in der Vergangenheit gelöst wurde.

---

Next Level: Nun kommt die Fähigkeit des Problemlösers hinzu. Bisher war nur von seiner Tätigkeit die Rede, nun geht es um seine Qualifikation.

> E: Er scheint die Aufgabe lösen zu können.

Im Satz E hat der Beobachter jetzt einen Eindruck, und der Problemlöser hat jetzt die erforderliche Befähigung das Problem jetzt zu lösen.

Wir haben nun drei Verben, die wir in die Vergangenheit versetzen könnten (scheinen, lösen, können):

- Der Anschein bestand in der Vergangenheit:

  > Er schien die Aufgabe lösen zu können.

  Jetzt ist es 10 Uhr. Der Beobachter hatte um 8:00 Uhr den Eindruck, dass die Fähigkeiten des Problemlösers ausreichend sind. Können und Eindruck fanden gleichzeitig um 8:00 Uhr statt.
- Der Beobachter hat jetzt einen Eindruck von der Vergangenheit:

  Dabei kann man das Verb *lösen* in die Vergangenheit setzen, oder auch das Verb *können.* Beginnen wir mit *»lösen«*:

  - etwas lösen → etwas gelöst haben

    > Er scheint die Aufgabe gelöst haben zu können.

    Das ist (bis auf die noch fehlende Verneinung) genau die Lösung, die bereits in der Frage vorgeschlagen wurde. Aber wir wollen eigentlich nicht über das Lösen reden, sondern über das Können, und daher muss dieses Verb in die Vergangenheitsform versetzt werden:
  - etwas können → etwas gekonnt haben

    > Er scheint die Aufgabe (zu?) lösen gekonnt zu haben.

    Über das eingeklammerte "zu" sage ich weiter unten noch etwas.
    Sehen wir uns zuerst einen einfacheren Satz an:

    > Er scheint Latein gekonnt zu haben.

    Oftmals lässt sich die gekonnte Sache auch durch ein Verb ausdrücken:

    > Er scheint jonglieren gekonnt zu haben.

    Aber manche Verben fühlen sich nackt an, wenn sie so allein im Infinitiv dastehen:

    > Er scheint lösen gekonnt zu haben.

    Da passt so nicht. Da muss man dazusagen, was er lösen konnte:

    > Er scheint die Aufgabe lösen gekonnt zu haben.
    > Er scheint die Aufgabe zu lösen gekonnt zu haben.

    Ich bin mir hier unsicher, ob auch vor "lösen" das Wort "zu" stehen muss/darf. Aber man kann die Reihenfolge der Satzbestandteile ändern:

    > Er scheint gekonnt zu haben, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

    Nun liegt ein ganz normaler erweiterter Infinitiv vor, und der braucht auf jeden Fall das Wort "zu". Es fehlt nur noch die Verneinung, und wir haben eine fertige Lösung:

    > Er scheint nicht gekonnt zu haben, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

    Weil das aber etwas sperrig klingt, möchte ich noch "können" durch "in der Lage sein" ersetzen:

    > Er scheint nicht in der Lage gewesen zu sein, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

    Auch das ist eine Lösung:

    > Allem Anschein nach war er nicht fähig, die Aufgabe zu lösen.

Answer (score -2):

> > Er scheint die Aufgabe nicht gelöst haben zu können.

Viel typischer ist die Formulierung *S'scheint, er habe ...*

Das Problem ist, dass "scheint" als Modalverb fungiert, das gar nicht als solches grammatikalisiert ist. Daher wirkt es wie Präsenz, obwohl die Endung relativ deutlich auf Konjunktiv hinweist (vgl. *ich mag, möchte*, *bin mächtig*). Somit scheiden weitere Modalverben aus der Betrachtung aus. Auch in @Janka's Darstellung wird *wollen* Vollverb behandelt.

Andererseits wird oberbairisch *scheints* gerne als Adverb ein- bzw. angefügt. Dem entspricht der Einschub *wie's scheint*.

In keinem Fall ist das wirkelich hohes deutsch. Daher erübrigt sich die Frage im Prinzip.

Ferner fällt im Vergleich mit englisch *it seems* der zu unterscheidende Nasal auf. Das ist, wie mir scheint, soweit ungeklärt. "Zufälle gibt's" ist keine Erklärung. *Shit happens for a reason*:

Denkbar wäre eine Ableitung aus einem Existenzquantifikator, zu dem *sein*, *sind, ist* gezählt werden (PIE **h1es-*, **h1s-enti*).

Die unterschiedlichen Nasale lassen sich auf Personen-Endungen zurückführen: engl. *am*, altsächsisch *bim* (“(ich) bin”), vgl. assimiliert *ich bi'mir unsicher*.

Wenn das stümpt, dürfte “Es stimmt” dazu gehören (*Stimme* ist insoweit unbestimmter Herkunft).

Ferner kennt man *schwanen* “ahnen”, refl. *mir schwant übles* ("Vielleicht entstanden durch Verschiebung der Wortgrenze zwischen Personalpronomen und Verb aus mnd. *es* (Genitiv) *wānet mir*", Pfeifer/DWDS).

Im Umkehrschluss heißt es immer noch, *Ich stimme zu, ich habe die Aufgabe nicht lösen können*. Ein zu-Partizip findet dort keinen rechten Platz.